# Capturing test output with XUnit.Net and VS2017

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, xunit.net

VS2017 Community Edition comes with test project templates for Xunit pre-installed. I have a Dotnet Standard 1.4 class library and a Dotnet Core 1.1 XUnit test project. This works well, everything builds, I can run all tests from the Visual Studio Test Explorer, and if my tests write to an ITestOutputHelper the Test Explorer shows an 'Output' link where I can view the output of the tests.

The problem is that if I have a load of tests I don't want to have to click on every test, and then on every 'Output' link in order to view the results. instead I want to see the results in some sort of output file.

The Xunit documentation indicates that it does have the ability to output test results in xml.

http://xunit.github.io/docs/format-xml-v2.html

But it doesn't explain how to get it to do it.

How can I get Xunit to save test output to a file?

Comment: Can you run the tests from the command line rather than VS Test Explorer? dotnet test -xml /some/path/out.xml. See thread https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3114

Answer (score 1):

xUnit logger can generate xml reports in the xUnit v2 format (https://xunit.github.io/docs/format-xml-v2.html).

1. Add a reference to the xUnit Logger nuget package in test project.
2. Use the following command line in tests:

   ```
   dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:xunit
   ```
3. Test results are generated in the `TestResults` directory relative to the `test.csproj`. A path for the report file can be specified as follows:

   ```
   dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:xunit;LogFilePath=loggerFile.xml
   ```

   `loggerFile.xml` will be generated in the same directory as `test.csproj`.